# WCF REST Service Denial of Service Defence

Tags: wcf, rest, denial-of-service, rate-limiting

I have created a WCF REST Search Service, and now want to know how to implement Denial of Service Defence to limit the number of request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your REST API is publicly reachable over the Internet, you should implement your safeguards the same way you would defend against a [DOS attack against a web](http://linuxgazette.net/126/cherian.html) site. There's really not going to be much difference in the approach, given that your RESTful service is (very likely) implemented using HTTP/HTTPS as the underlying application transport.